# Issues with printer share on Debian Samba server, jobs not getting sent to server

Tags: debian, samba, network-printer, cups, hp-officejet

I'm having quite a bit of issues with getting my printer shared on my Debian 8.

I have an HP Officejet 4500 g510n-z hooked in via USB to the machine. It is detected:

```
root@bahamut:/etc/samba# lsusb
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 03f0:2e12 Hewlett-Packard
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

When I plug the printer in it is being detected by the OS via syslog:

```
Dec  1 21:36:47 bahamut colord: Device added: cups-HP_Officejet_4500_G510n-z
```

I have it configured in my `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf`:

```
<DefaultPrinter HP_Officejet_4500_G510n-z>
UUID urn:uuid:eb4c2bf6-dadc-3980-6e54-592432cb7f89
Info HP Officejet
Location
DeviceURI hp:/usb/Officejet_4500_G510n-z?serial=CN1BBK32CW05HR
State Idle
StateTime 1480651643
Type 8425484
Accepting Yes
Shared No
JobSheets none none
QuotaPeriod 0
PageLimit 0
KLimit 0
AllowUser jguy
OpPolicy default
ErrorPolicy stop-printer
</Printer>
```

lpstat shows the printer there and accepting jobs:

```
root@bahamut:/etc/cups# lpstat -a
HP_Officejet_4500_G510n-z accepting requests since Thu 01 Dec 2016 10:07:23 PM CST
```

I can use the CUPS web console to print a test page and it prints successfully.

I have the following in my `/etc/samba/smb.conf` to share it:

```
[global]
    passdb backend = tdbsam
    obey pam restrictions = yes
    syslog = 0
    usershare allow guests = yes
    map to guest = bad user
    null passwords = yes
    dns proxy = no
    max log size = 1000
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    os level = 20
    unix password sync = yes
    server role = standalone server
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    load printers = yes
    encrypt passwords = yes
    pam password change = yes
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u

[HPOfficeJet]
    path = /var/spool/printer
    printer driver = hp:/usb/Officejet_4500_G510n-z
    public = yes
    printable = yes
    printer = HP_Officejet_4500_G510n-z
```

I have some samba file shares on this same machine and they are working correctly. I can connect to the printer via my Devices and Printers on my Windows 10 machine and it shows up successfully. However, any print jobs sent to the printer are not queued or executed on the server, so nothing prints from clients.

Anything you can see that I missed or overlooked? Thanks for any help.